# Python Beautiful Soup find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to get some information from a website. Pardon me if I formatted anything wrong this is my first time posting to SO.

```
soup.find('div', {"class":"stars"})
```

From this I receive

```
<div class="stars" title="4.0 star rating">
<i class="star star--large star-0"></i><i class="star star--large star- 
1"></i><i class="star star--large star-2"></i><i class="star star--large 
star-3"></i><i class="star star--large star-4 star--large--muted"></i> 
</div>
```

I need that `"4.0 star rating"`

When I use:

```
soup.find('div', {"class":"stars"})["title"]
```

It works, but not for find_all. But I'm trying to find all cases and put them into a list.

This is my full code below.

```
    def get_info():
        from IPython.display import HTML
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        n = 1
        for page in range(53):
            url = f"https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/apple.com?page= 
   {n}&sort=Reviews.processed&direction=DESC#reviews"
            r = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            all_reviews = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"truncate_review"})
            all_dates = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'review__date'},'title')
            all_titles = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'review__title__text'})
            reviews_class = soup.find('div', {"class":"review__stars"})
            for review in all_reviews:

    all_reviews_list.append(review.text.replace("\n","").replace("\t",""))
            for date in all_dates:

all_dates_list.append(date.text.replace("\n","").replace("\t",""))
            for title in all_titles:

  all_titles_list.append(title.text.replace("\n","").replace("\t",""))
            for stars in reviews_class.find_all('div', {'class':'stars'}):
                all_star_ratings.append(stars['title'])



            n += 1
```

Sorry my indenting got a bit messed up but that is my full code.

Comment: while you do page in rang(), do you need another variable n ?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese  I'm using n to change the page number when it cycles through in the f-string but I suppose I could start the range at 1 and put page in the f-string. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse through the bs4 element as you do in dictionary.
If you are using `find()`:

```
soup.find('div', {"class":"stars"}) ['title']
```

this works since `find()` returns a single value.
But if you are using `find_all()`, it returns a list and `list[string]` is an invalid process.
Therefore, you can create a list of those:

```
res = []
for i in soup.find_all('div', {"class":"stars"}):
    res.append(i['title'])
```

else, as a one-liner:

```
res = [i['title'] for i in soup.find_all('div', {"class":"stars"})]
```

---

Since you want all titles of the reviews, you need to specify the review container, that is, **scrape** from:

```
<div class="review__container">
```

So the code will be:

```
review = soup.find_all('div',class_="review__container")
res = [i['title'] for j in review for i in j.find_all('div',class_='stars')]
```

gives:

```
['1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '3.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '5.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '5.0 star rating', '2.0 star rating', '5.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '2.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '5.0 star rating', '1.0 star rating', '5.0 star rating']
```

Comment: Hi Joshua maybe I shouldve posted all my code. I had find a different class first and store it in a variable and then find again. Or else I would take stars scores before the reviews. I tried what you said but it seemed to return the same answer over and over in the list.                      reviews_class = soup.find('div', {"class":"review__stars"})  for stars in reviews_class.find_all('div', {'class':'stars'}):
            all_star_ratings.append(stars['title'])                        This gave me 1 star 1 star 1 star ......

Comment: My problem is this is a review website. I'm focused on the reviews. Earlier in the page there are star scores for the store and other aspects. I only need the star scores pertaining to the reviews themselves and not the composite scores at the top of the page. Just to clarify

Answer (score 0):

*How about the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="stars" title="4.0 star rating">
<i class="star star--large star-0"></i><i class="star star--large star- 
1"></i><i class="star star--large star-2"></i><i class="star star--large 
star-3"></i><i class="star star--large star-4 star--large--muted"></i> 
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
element = soup.select('.stars')[0]['title']
print(element)
```

---

*Prints*

> ```
> 4.0 star rating
> ```

---

*using the url*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/apple.com?page={n}&sort=Reviews.processed&direction=DESC#reviews'
page = requests.get(url=url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features="lxml")

elements = soup.select('.stars')
# print(elements)

for element in elements:
    print(element['title'])
```

---

*Prints*

```
4.0 star rating
3.8 star rating
3.7 star rating
4.3 star rating
3.8 star rating
4.2 star rating
0.0 star rating
0.0 star rating
5.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
3.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
5.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
5.0 star rating
2.0 star rating
5.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
2.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
5.0 star rating
1.0 star rating
5.0 star rating
4.3 star rating
3.5 star rating
4.7 star rating
3.7 star rating
4.8 star rating
3.7 star rating
```

Comment: this does work nicely but I need to skip the first few star scores and make sure they start displaying from the reviews section and secondly I need it for all instances and to store in a list. Thank you for the help

Comment: is there any way to start it from a specific part of the html. My problem is this is a review website. I'm focused on the reviews. Earlier in the page there are star scores for the store and other aspects. I only need the star scores pertaining to the reviews themselves and not the composite scores at the top of the page.

Comment: @JGW sure do you wanna start from `review__flex`?